# How to manage versions and deployment of XML schemas and classes generated thereof?

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb

We maintain multiple projects that communicate via XML.
The interfaces are defined in XML schemas (`.xsd` files).
We use JAXB to generate classes from those schemas that are then used in the projects.
We also use the `.xsd` files to validate input or output.

Sometimes, we need to update the schemas to create a new version that may or may not be backwards compatible.

How can we effectively manage these schemas? Projects should be able to select which version(s) of the schemas they want to work with. It would be nice if every project's build didn't have to integrate and maintain the class generation step again. Are there any good practices for this?

I'm currently thinking about two options:

1. Package the generated classes as an artifact and deploy them to a Maven repo from where projects can pull them in. Projects don't have to deal with the class generation but access to the `.xsd` file itself becomes more complicated.
2. Pull the schemas into the projects as Git submodules. This gives simple access to the schema file but each project's build has to bother with generating the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, JAXB (and XML data binding generally) is a bad idea unless the schema is very stable. You may be using the wrong technology. Working with multiple versions of the schema means you are working with multiple versions of compiled Java code, and that's always going to be a maintenance nightmare.

It may not be a helpful suggestion, but my advice is, don't start from here. If multiple versions of the schema need to coexist, then you want a technology where the application doesn't need to be recompiled every time there is a schema change; look at either a generic low-level API such as JDOM2 or XOM, or a declarative XML-oriented language such as XSLT, XQuery, or LINQ.

Comment: I should clarify: The projects don't use multiple versions of the same schema at once. They may use multiple different schemas, though. Also, I'm not starting from here. These schemas already exist but I want a better way to manage the entire thing.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that I once earned a nice little consultancy fee for trying to help a client who had dug themselves into this hole, without really finding a good solution; so ever since then, I have tried to encourage other people not to dig themselves into the same hole.